# Prevent UIWebView From Scrolling Too Far

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, custom-scrolling

I have two buttons, a scroll up and a scroll down that are used to scroll the webpage in a `UIWebView`. The only issue is, once they hit the top or bottom of the page they can keep scrolling. They can scroll until the entire webpage is off of the `UIWebView`. Does anyone know what code I need to plug in to prevent this from happening? I've been researching for a while now and it is all going over my head. Is it even possible to detect where the webpage has ended? This is the code I'm using to scroll, I have a feeling I need to throw an `if` statement in here to check if it has hit the top of the webpage.

```
    //Scroll Up:
-(IBAction)scrollContentUp:(id)sender {

    [_viewWeb.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,_viewWeb.scrollView.contentOffset.y - 40.0) animated:YES];

}

//Scroll down:
-(IBAction)scrollContentDown:(id)sender {
    [_viewWeb.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,_viewWeb.scrollView.contentOffset.y + 40.0) animated:YES];

}
```

By the way, it's an iPad only app.

Comment: Can't you just keep track of the pixels that the content is scrolled up or down and cease scrolling if it reaches a certain value?

Comment: I think that's what I need to do, the only problem is I have no idea how to it. I'm still very new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+You need to do something like:

```
   //Scroll Up:
-(IBAction)scrollContentUp:(id)sender {
    if(_webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y - 40 >= 0) {
        [_viewWeb.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,
                                    _viewWeb.scrollView.contentOffset.y - 40.0) 
                                     animated:YES];
    }
}

//Scroll down:
-(IBAction)scrollContentDown:(id)sender {
    if(_webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y + _webView.frame.size.height + 40 <= _viewWeb.scrollView.contentSize.height ) {
            [_viewWeb.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,
                                        _viewWeb.scrollView.contentOffset.y + 40.0) 
                                         animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: There was a - sign that should have been +

Comment: Oh okay that explains it. Thank you again for everything!